# Adding dynamically several Button to several LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

I would like to add buttons to different LinearLayout dynamically (with Java) but before that I have to add `LinearLayout` to the main View which is also a `LinearLayout` by the way.

Here is my code:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game);

    globalLinear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.viewButtons);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    LinearLayout row = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_buttons, globalLinear);

    for(int i = 1; i <= nbButton; i++) {
        if(i % 3 == 0) {
             row = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_buttons, globalLinear);
        }
        Button b = new Button(this);
            int number = generator.nextInt(complexity);

            b.setText(number+"");
            row.addView(b, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                           LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) );    
    }
}
```

`R.id.viewButtons` is the main (vertical) `LinearLayout` inside.
`R.layout.row_buttons` is a horizontal `LinearLayout`.

As you can see above, I am trying to get 3 buttons per `LinearLayout` with `(i % 3 == 0)`
But it seems new `LinearLayout` are never created.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Hmm, the code seems to look okay, but I haven't tested it. What views are shown?

Is all your XML okay? Have you defined layout height and with attributes?

Comment: I have 10 buttons but each one is in a LinearLayout (so 10 LinearLayout).
I don't think my XML are wrong and yes, height and width are defined. To my mind, this is just about instanciate a new LinearLayout... But how?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to define the linear layout, create new instance of it within the loop for it to be created as long as the loop execute.

Comment: Exactly, I think I have to create a new instance of LinearLayout but I don't know how to instanciate a new one with inflate...

Comment: You might wanna create the Layout inflater inside the for loop. At the moment, it is only being created ones. It is worth trying that way.

Comment: Nope! I still have 10 LinearLayout :(